# Navigation and Footer links are together in Safari

Tags: html, css

I've been having an issue whenever I see my website on Safari. For some reason, my navigation and footer links are clumped together like this

[navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3PdU.png)
[footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3gOK.png)

Code:

```css
#john_perez_logo{
    width: 80px;
}

.menu{
    color: #FAFAFA;
}
.menu:hover{
    color: #FF2727;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#my_community_footer{
    background-color: #012039;
    width: 100%;
}

.social_media {
    padding: 50px;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #2d2d2d90;
}



/*Navigation*/
nav{
    max-width: 1200px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.logo{
    float: left;
}

.navigation{
float: right;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
list-style-type: none;
gap: 35px;
padding-top: 20px;
}

#menu{
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.menu{
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.-webkit-a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
}

html{
scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/*Dropdown*/
```

```html
<!--Navigation-->
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img id="john_perez_logo" src="./assets/jp.svg" alt="Johnathan Perez"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation">
                <div class="portfolio_dropdown">
                    <a href="index.html" class="menu"><span style="color: #F87475;">CASE STUDIES &#8964;</span></a>
                    <div class="portfolio_dropdown_menu">
                        <a href="./pages/my_community.html" class="dropdown">MY COMMUNITY</a><br>
                        <a href="./pages/project_connect.html" class="dropdown">PROJECT CONNECT</a><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="./pages/about.html" class="menu">ABOUT</a> 
            </div>
        </nav>

 <!--Footer-->
        <footer>
            <div class="social_media">
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/john_perez52/" target="_blank"><img src="./assets/icons/social/instagram.svg" alt="Instagram" style="width: 24px;"></a>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/johnathan-perez-b23261218/" target="_blank"><img src="./assets/icons/social/linkedin.svg" alt="Linkedin" style="width: 24px;"></a>
                <a href="https://github.com/johnperez52" target="_blank"><img src="./assets/icons/social/github.svg" alt="Git Hub" style="width: 24px;"></a>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/johnperez1998" target="_blank"><img src="./assets/icons/social/facebook.svg" alt="Facebook" style="width: 24px;"></a>
               
            </div>
        </footer>
```

I'm using an **a** tag for them. It only does this for a tag for some reason. Does anybody know why it does this in safari and how I can fix this issue?

I tried using WebKit, but it is not working, maybe I'm using it the wrong way? But this is only for Safari browser.

Comment: I don't seem to have this issue when running the code you provided

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write the 'margin css' just for Safari web browser.